# P channel mosfet failure gate to source short

Tags: mosfet

i have using P channel mosfet for high side switching. the mosfet was frequenctly failed . i.e the gate to source shorted . resistance forming across the gate to source of MOSFET. the load power i have using less than 0.5W only. even though the MOSFET continously failed. To switch on the MOSFET the gate of mosfet is i give striagh ground . is it the reason for forming resistance across the gate to source.

Comment: post your circuit also.It may help us to give exact answer

Comment: Apart from the circuit, the part number of the specific device you are using will be useful.

Comment: Things that kill mosfets are: Overvoltage (including really fast inductive spikes), overcurrent (including really brief spikes) and overtemperature, those are the three main ones, it only takes microseconds to kill a mosfet

Comment: I would guess that you're exceeding the Vgs rating of your MOSFET, but since you haven't told us what MOSFET you have or shown us how you've connected it I could be wrong...

Answer (score 2):

I have found the reason for mosfet failure ( i.e gate to source damage ).
high spike voltage in the gate terminal is the reason damage. the high voltage spike from the soldering ion station. i have using only branded ion only. eventhough the high voltage spike comming from the soldering road. the high voltage spike affecting the mosfet isolated gate terminal. i have tried i different MOSFET the same problems is happening. i have tried in another soldering station this problems is not comming . then only i have found the voltage spike from the soldering station only.